# Cross Platform Portable Web Server - HTTP

Tags: java, http

Can someone let me know the Cross Platform Portable Web Server - HTTP  to test static or dynamic web-sites and make it portable?

Thanks

Comment: Jetty? Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Anything is fine..Pls let me know